# Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "implements"

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, contentful

After downloading the contentful plugin and setting it up for my gatsby site, I try running "npm run develop" but when I run it the following error appears:
Encountered an error parsing the provided GraphQL type definitions:
Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "implements"

They show that the error is in this code:

```
interface ContentfulEntry implements Node {                       
    contentful_id: String!
    id: ID!
    node_locale: String!
}
```

However, I can't find the file which has this code nor have I written it.

Comment: Looks like Java code, which I guess is part of the plug-in? My guess would be the run process is wrong, or something went wrong installing. Can you provide links to products and the instructions you are following in your question?

Comment: This is the link to the plugin I am using: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/?=con

Comment: I have tried reinstalling again and again by deleting all the files related to the contentful plugin in node_modules so I don't think so it is a problem with the installation.

Comment: @IainBallard it looks nothing like Java, except the works `interface` and `implements`. It seems like TypeScript or Flow. You don't write the type after `:` in Java - you start the line with them; there is no `!` for types; the code lacks semicolons to make it compilable. A valid line would be `String contenful_id;` and even then, you cannot declare properties in interfaces (well, you sort of can in Java 8+ but not like shown here). Furthermore, interfaces cannot implement other interfaces, they can extend them.

Comment: `node.js`+`gatsby` tags - discussion about java doesn't make sense ... `interface xxxx implements` is obviously wrong [in graphql, too] ... search (source+packages) for "ContentfulEntry" only? - graphql code not wrapped in `gql` tag/literal?

Comment: As it has been said, it's not Java, it's TypeScript coming from some `node_modules` (I assume that is from Contentful plugin). I would suggest removing them all, and reinstalling again, as well clean the cache by  `gatsby clean`, just to be sure

Comment: I've ran into the same problem and tried cleaning everything out to no avail. I found out that I was using an older version of `graphql` (14.6.0), updated to the latest version (15.5.0) and I'm now getting a different error. Potentially that's the fix?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. I've changed "gatsby-source-contentful" version from 5.1.1 to 4.6.3 and it worked...

Comment: Which package did you revert?

Comment: @JoshBowden it's "gatsby-source-contentful". I have updated my reply

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Gatsby you are using? Gatsby-source-contentful 5 seems to require Gatsby 3. I got a warning in that regard before the error.

I guess this has to do with Graphql version differences. See this: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/v3.0/#graphql-15